# How to read and print data from a dictionary using a modal operator?

Tags: python, scripting, operator

The following code creates a dictionary and prints it at regular intervals:

```
import bpy
import json

class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    _timer = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            dict = {"a":4}

            msg = 'testDict = '+json.dumps(dict)+'\n'
            msg += 'list = ["a","b","c"]\n'

            msg += 'def printTestFunc(num1,num2):\n'
            msg += '    print(num1)\n'
            msg += '    print(num2)\n'

            msg += 'for i in range(5):\n'
            msg += '    [printTestFunc(0,testDict[key]) for key in list if key in testDict]\n'
            exec(msg)

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.1, window=context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```

Unfortunately, it returns the following error:

> line 28, in modal
>     File "", line 7, in 
>     File "", line 7, in 
>     NameError: name 'testDict' is not defined

However, when I write the following code using Python without using Blender's ModalOperator there is no error:

```
import json

dict = {"a":4}

msg = 'testDict = '+json.dumps(dict)+'\n'
msg += 'list = ["a","b","c"]\n'

msg += 'def printTestFunc(num1,num2):\n'
msg += '    print(num1)\n'
msg += '    print(num2)\n'

msg += 'for i in range(5):\n'
msg += '    [printTestFunc(0,testDict[key]) for key in list if key in testDict]\n'
exec(msg)
```

I think this is a *Modal Operator* specific trouble. Why does this happen?

Comment: While it's certainly interesting why this doesn't work, I'm wondering why you're dynamically creating code and using `exec()` in the first place? Is there any specific reason why you can't simply call a function and pass the the json data as an argument?

Comment: I'm writing code that generates commands on other machines and sends them to Blender over TCP / IP. Therefore, I use `exec()` in this sample.

Comment: Oh no. Please DO NOT do that. You're basically creating a remote code execution vulnerability as a "feature".

Comment: As a security measure, I wrote a process that will not execute if the sent string contains the string "import". Then I can only use Blender's bpy command, but is it still dangerous?

Comment: Yes it's still very dangerous. First of all the question is whether or not your check works properly and even if it does, the attacker can still use any module you've already imported. Given that you're opening sockets that's likely a lot more than just bpy. Please inform yourself about the security risks of such code and how to properly implement a server API. You never want a client to be able to execute arbitrary code on your server.

Comment: Okay, I try a method that doesn't use exec().

Comment: Also as a side note, Blender's Python API assumes that you what you're doing. There are plenty ways to make Blender crash due to a segfault, e.g. a wrong custom context passed to an operator. This could potentially be leveraged for an exploit that doesn't rely on any imports at all.

Comment: @RobertGützkow what about the _`Text Editor > Templates > Python > External Script Stub`_

Comment: @batFINGER Depends on how you intend to use this in a client / server context. If the server has a set of scripts and the client can only choose between running one of these, then it would be fine. If you're suggesting that a client could upload their own file and the server would run it like in the template, that's still a firm no, since it has the same security problems as before.

Comment: NP misread comment as "don't use exec" full stop. Which I have seen often.   Totally agree re client server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pass a `globals` dict to `exec`**

Not sure of the reason why it doesn't work.. only have some inklings.

However can populate a dictionary and pass as globals to the `exec` function.

```
        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            mydict = {"a":4}
            myglobals = {"testDict": eval(json.dumps(mydict)),
                       "mylist": ["a","b","c"] }

            msg = 'def printTestFunc(num1,num2):\n'
            msg += '    print(num1)\n'
            msg += '    print(num2)\n'

            msg += 'for i in range(5):\n'
            msg += '    [printTestFunc(0,testDict[key]) for key in mylist if key in testDict]\n'
            exec(msg, myglobals, None)

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}
```

Alternatively could define vars in the method and pass `locals()` which will include `self, context` and `event`

Note: Good idea not to use builtins like `list` and `dict` for variable names.  EDIT: Oops did just that with `globals`

Comment: Thanks, the code worked fine!